# React Native: is importing local .json async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a local `.json` file that I wish to use as a starting point for my state. I then plan to store the state in `AsyncStorage`. But my concern is that the import is async and I will get some conflicts.

This is what I'm currently doing

```
import { data } from './src/data.json'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data,
    }

    this.updatePitch = this.updatePitch.bind(this)
  }
...
}
```

But should I do this instead?

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setState({ data })
  }
```

(I'm seeing some layout issues when doing it and a lot of warnings about other life-cycle methods will be deprecated)

and then perhaps do some `Promise.all` when trying to hook it up with `AsyncStorage`?

What the best way to use a local `.json` file as a `"boilerplate/template"` and then store the revised version locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing bundled json is synchronous (it's just like importing from a js file).

Your constructor is fine.

If you use Redux, you can import the json and use it as the initial state in your reducer. You can then persist the Redux state with [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). Redux is highly recommended unless your app is really simple.

Otherwise, you can simply store the state to `AsyncStorage` whenever it's updated, and read from `AsyncStorage` in `componentDidMount` and call `setState` with the stored state for initialisation.

> a lot of warnings about other life-cycle methods will be deprecated

This is a bug in RN 0.55.1, upgrade to >=0.55.2 to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not too fund of `redux`, so I'll stick with storing it after `setState` is called.